# Remove character from a DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I am trying to remove a trailing exclamation mark from the following:

```
<div class="onsale">Sale!</div
```

Tried with jQuery and JS but going around in circles.
thanks

Comment: Well then show us some of those circles.

Comment: Fair... $(".onsale").html().replace('!', '');

Comment: That is only replacing the value in the string you _read_, you need to write it back to the element afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have attached a simple jQuery example that will remove the last character.

```js
var currentVal = $('.onsale').html()
var trimmedVal = currentVal.slice(0,-1)
$('.onsale').html(trimmedVal)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="onsale">Sale!</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var value = $(".onsale").html();
  alert(value.slice(0,4));
});
```